# Back Stack in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, back-stack

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app. In that I need to to navigate from

```
Page1 --> Page2--> Page3
```

But I don't want **Page1** to apper again when I keep on pressing back button.

```
Page3-->Page2-->Exit the app
```

I was able to achieve this using **Frame.BackStack.Clear()** in the **OnNavigatedFrom()** of **Page1**. But the problem is when I click the app icon again its only launching from Page2 not from Page1.

```
So I want to understand, why the back stack is not  cleared when we press 
back button and exit the app. And how to achieve the behavior I require
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 8.1 Store apps do not **close** when you are navigating back from the first page. Instead they only get **suspended**. So once you start open it again, you end up on the last running instance of the app again, this includes backstack, page state, etc.

In the app.xaml.Cs's **OnLaunched** handler, you can intercept this behavior: You can check the **e.PreviousExecutionState** where you can check, if you want to handle it as a real *restart*.

In that case you just dump the current Frame and replace it with a new one, or clear the backstack and start with a new navigation.

Also: The Backstack is a list. You can remove single entries any time and not only completely clear it with the *RemoveAt* method.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods sounds okay to me. It is that the app runs behind the scene. Unless you write a code like this it will keep running in the last position you kept.

```
Application.Current.Exit();
```